# String.repalceAll() not working?

Tags: java

```
String points;
        String points2;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            try {
                cursor = dbEditor.getPoints(params[0]);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                strPoints = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("points"));
                points = "points:"+strPoints;
                points = points.replace(')','}');
                points = points.replace('(','{');
                points2 = points.replace("lat\"/lng: ","");
```

The Result still is :

> points:["lat/lng: {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499843,26.5009921}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499329,26.5009746}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499114,26.5009419}","lat/lng:
>   {43.8499114,26.5009419}","lat/lng: {43.8499114,26.5009419}"]

Any suggestions why `replaceAll()` not working?

Comment: where is your not working `replaceAll()` ?

Comment: you are not using `replaceAll`, you are using `replace`

Comment: Why are you trying to escape the '/' character in the last line?

Comment: anyway... replaceAll() not working too... not replacing that substring with " " empty string..

Comment: Despite the fact that you are not using the replaceAll(); why should it do a replace, there is no `lat"/lng:`

Comment: where is your replaceAll() ??

Comment: I have tried any kind of variations  but still not replacing this substring..

Answer (score 0):

I see that your `)` and `(` are replaced with `}` and `{`,

```
"lat/lng: {43.8499843,26.5009921}"
```

What not replaced is `lat/long`. Because you are replacing `lat"/lng:` which the string doesn't have.

The String has `lat//lang`.

So your last replace has to be.

```
points = points.replace("lat//lng: ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last replace should be like this:-

```
points2 = points.replaceAll("lat\\/lng: ","");
```

See the code below:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str="lat/lng: {43.8499843,26.5009921}\",\"lat/lng: {43.8499843,26.5009921}\",\"lat/lng: ";
    //Problem is the first expression of replaceAll is a regex so, / has a special meaning
    //in regex, you need to escape it
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("lat\\/lng:", ""));
}

Output: {43.8499843,26.5009921}"," {43.8499843,26.5009921}","
```